# What are some good resources on doing text-to-speech in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, text-to-speech

Can anybody help me with Text to Speech Engine in C#

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Microsoft Speech SDK

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa920210.aspx

Just for simple t2s, it should be very simple, like

```
SpVoice objSpeech = new SpVoice();
objSpeech.Speak("Hello world",SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFlagsAsync);
objSpeech.WaitUntilDone(Timeout.Infinite);
```

Comment: How can I add my own? I am trying to create a TTS app for greek and I am trying to create a Lexicon and I need some guidelines. Here is my question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102319/i-need-help-creating-a-lexicon-for-speechsynthesizer-a-template-of-some-kind-so