# I need help creating a lexicon for SpeechSynthesizer. A template of some kind so i can know how to create one

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-c++, text-to-speech

More or less what the title says. I wish to create a lexicon of greek text to speech so I can make my language for SpeechSynthesizer. Where can I find a template of some kind?? Or some guidelines???? Or anything you can possibly offer is acceptable as there is no greek suppport in SpeechSynthesizer. But i need it to be my own creation. Not some third party app. SDKs, header files, libraries, apis all accepted. Just no ready apps that have greek text to speech

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample with only 1 word (blue).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<lexicon version="1.0" 
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/01/pronunciation-lexicon"
      alphabet="x-microsoft-ups" xml:lang="en-US">


  <lexeme>
    <grapheme> blue </grapheme>
    <phoneme> B L I P </phoneme>
  </lexeme>

</lexicon>
```

this was taken from:  [MSDN - Click here for the full article.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.addlexicon.aspx)
I would also suggesr reading [Pronunciation Lexicon Reference (Microsoft.Speech)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh378339%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: I kind of gave up on this project as I wanted to create a lexicon for greek but I do not understand how to tell the system how to pronounce a greek word