# How Can I download Text to Speech data from google translate?

Tags: c#, google-translate, text-to-speech

I am trying to create an app that speaks Greek. But since Microsoft does not support Greek as a spoken language and my question on guidelines on how to create my own lexicon ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102319/i-need-help-creating-a-lexicon-for-speechsynthesizer-a-template-of-some-kind-so)) I am asking this:

How may I download an mp3 (or just the data doesn't matter) that includes the text that I sent to google translate on runtime and play it using C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just use this link to download the MP3:

```
http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=el&q=%22hello%22
```

Edit:
Be aware Some Browsers like Firefox replaces the %22 with " and the link doesnt work so you need to copy it and cant click it!

How to Download Files:
http://www.csharp-examples.net/download-files/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe.aspx

How to Play MP3:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y171b18.aspx

```
using System.Media;

String strTextYouWantAsMp3 = "Hello";
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile("http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=el&q=%22" + strTextYouWantAsMp3 + "%22", @"c:\audio.mp3");

SoundPlayer simpleSound = new SoundPlayer(@"c:\audio.mp3");
simpleSound.Play();
```

Comment: Firstly what is the difference between downloading files synchronously and asynchronously??
Second what does firefox have to do with everything? (maybe I understood your answer wrong
Third I wish to send the text to google translate and get the tts all from my code and not just get a link from a browser. It will be done at runtime

Comment: 1.if you download it synchronously you cant do anythin other than downloading (your UI will freeze)
2.doesnt matter because i used a codebox for the link so u cant click it.
3.yeah u need to download the file given from the link with webClient.DownloadFile(Link)

Comment: This example does not work. `SoundPlayer` does not play MP3s. It says so specifically in the [MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer(v=vs.110).aspx). The only thing I've found is to use the WMPLib COM control to be able to play MP3s.

Comment: Google has blocked this behavior effective November 2015.

Answer (score 3):

This link is now broken, you can refer to Chris Cirefice answer here:
[Google Text-To-Speech API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9893175/google-text-to-speech-api)

As suggested you will need to make a get request against the following URL
**http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=Hello%20World&client=t** 
where `q={your word you want to translate}` and `tl={your language}`